# multiple jquery slide toggle not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i click on the first toggle it works correctly. but the second  does not opens.
if i change 'panel' from id to class both  toggles at same time.
i want to do if i click on 1st , only 1st toggles and when on 2nd one only 2nd toggles.

**HTML**

```
<div id="flip"><a href='#'>Android Hacker's Book</a></div>
<div id="panel">
    <img src="images/Android Hack $38.32.jpg"></img>
    Price: $38.32.61
</div>
<div id="flip"><a href='#'>Advanced C & C++ Compiling</a></div>
<div id="panel">
    <img src="images/Advanced c $57.61.jpg"></img>
    Price: $57.61
</div>
```

**Script**
script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function()
    {
        $(this).next('#panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#panel
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: and what's the problem exactly? Could you provide a fiddle, explaining what's wrong and what is the expected behaviour? Could you give further information?

Comment: Define: `not working`.

Comment: ID's must be unique Here: http://jsfiddle.net/tDv9U/

Comment: i just edited it. can you help now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `id` must be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<div class="flip">
    <a href='#'>Android Hacker's Book</a>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <img src="images/Android Hack $38.32.jpg" />
    Price: $38.32.61
</div>
<div class="flip">
    <a href='#'>Advanced C & C++ Compiling</a>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <img src="images/Advanced c $57.61.jpg" />
    Price: $57.61
</div>
```

then you can use `.` to target elements by class name:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Please note that `<img />` is a self-closing tag, you need to use `<img />` instead of `<img></img>`

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A3wJN/)**